# How to deploy "Eclipse Backups" from personal folder to a Sandbox?

Tags: deployment

As part of Sandbox refresh, we have archived a copy of all files through eclipse force.come IDE environment for a full Sandbox into a local folder.After the Sandbox refresh completed, now we need to deploy only the required files (approx 80 files) which might be pages,class,trigger,static resources etc.,. into a another Sandbox (it is s full sandbox which has production's copy after the refresh) again. So, is there any possibility to deploy the codes into Sandbox from local archived folder using Eclipse Force.com IDE?. I read this could be possible using ANT tool but I would like to know if there is any alternative approach to do this? Appreciate for any ideas on this.

Comment: Hmm interesting additional information.. I will give it some thought

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I have understood your requirement correctly here, but I would personally just copy the files that I wanted to deploy from the archived folder, into their respective folder on the operating system that the new project is deployed to. In Eclipse you can find out where the workspace folder is by selecting "Properties" from the right hand click context menu on the project name in the navigator, and then select "Resource":

[image: properties]

Head over to this folder and copy in the "right" or "new" versions of the files you want into their relevant subfolders. New files will of course just copy, most operating systems will warn you of a file replacement.

Then in Eclipse, click on the new project title, and hit F5 to refresh it (or select Refresh from the right click context menu) this will re-scan the source folders for these changes. Once the project has pulled in all the new and updated files, you can "Deploy" the files to the server.

You can either whip through and select all the changed files by hand and then right click, and from the "Force.com" menu select "Deploy to Server" and then follow the easy deployment wizard.

[image: deploy files]

or you can just right click on the project title and select the same deploy option and follow the wizard through.

This will push the local copies of the files up to the new Sandbox, and I hope, that is what you are trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for your response Simon. Yes, This is what I am expecting. But before I try this, I could not do refresh from server in eclipse since I am getting a weird error message as "Cannot Write to File" File/ForceDotComRedesignPhase1/Referenced Packages/C5r_Desktop_oauth/package.xml is read only."". But anyway I will try the suggested solution once I am able to login in with server copy and post my update here for any queries/resolved my problem.

Comment: So are you having trouble with the *new* Sandbox syncing into Eclipse?

Comment: Yes Simon, I am unable to sync Sandbox with Eclipse. Actually I was able to sync with Sandbox in first time when I created the project within Eclipse. There after I could not sync with the server.

Comment: I am still looking for a way to how to get rid of the issue "Cannot Write to File" File/ForceDotComRedesignPhase1/Referenced Packages/C5r_Desktop_oauth/package.xml is read only.". Any idea would be more helpful to analyse the issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is one more easy option available. You can visit to [WORKBENCH](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php) and after authenticating with your sandbox, you will get the option 'Migration-->Deploy' in the menu. Where you can choose the zipped files you exported from eclipse. Rest will be done by Workbench.